# How to integrate Neo4j database and GraphQL in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, neo4j, graphql

At the moment I have a microservice (ASP.NET Core Web API) that handles arbitrary integration events and writes data to the Neo4j database. As a next step, I need to offer API to users and I need to use GraphQL.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to integrate Neo4j database, GraphQL and dotnet. As far as I see it is possible to integrate GraphQL, dotnet and EF Core using [graphql-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet), [graphql-net](https://github.com/chkimes/graphql-net) or [hotchocolate](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate), but I don't see any option for Neo4j database. Is this possible?

I've seen that the hotchocolate has a plan for [Neo4j integration](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/2325), but that is still a work in progress.

I've seen that graphql-dotnet states on [this page](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/databases) that it is possible to use any data source with it, but I am not sure how to approach this. Can you provide me some examples?

> This library will work with **any data source** that you provide. Here are a few resources for specific data sources.

In addition, I would like to ask if it is possible to combine multiple databases (PostgreSQL with EF Core and Neo4j) into one composite GraphQL that will be exposed to clients?

Comment: Hi Gzsum,  did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Not really. I am not familiar with a solution that is production-ready. However, if you just want to explore how that might work you can go to https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/tree/neo4j/src/HotChocolate/Neo4J , download the source code, build the project, and reference .dll (you got after the build has succeeded) from your project. Hotchocolate managed to provide the basic functionalities and it's possible to integrate everything together, but that's still a work in progress.

Comment: Be aware that if you decide to go with this approach you will lack documentation and that your only resource for including this on the project will be the source code and the tests available on the Github repository. So, be careful with this (since it's not really available and it's not intended to be used this way).

Comment: Thank you, my research has concluded the same.  From a graph DB perspective, I am also looking at CosmosDB Graph DB.  I am a ways off from implementing any Graph store but We are heavily vested in Azure (and like it) and we are further heavily vested in CosmosDB (SQL) on the OLTP side of things.  I am currently testing ChilleCream's HotChocolate's Mongo Extension over a projection of the Cosmos (SQL) OLTP instance into a CosmosDB (Mongo API) to see how well/or not, that performs for our needs.  Hope to achieve domain wide GraphQL overarching that projection.